# How do I Assign directory path to a variable during mkdir in shell script without cd?

Tags: linux, shell, mkdir

I have a shell script where I am

making directory structure:

```
mkdir -p /root/project/log
mkdir -p /root/project/graphs
mkdir -p /root/project/source
mkdir -p /root/project/config
```

I have variables to make my script readable.

```
LOGPATH = 
GRAPHPATH =
SOURCEPATH =
CONFIGPATH =
```

How do I assign these variables **during mkdir** itself?

I want the actual path description to stay just in one place.

I dont like to cd and assign pwd.

Comment: Why not assign values to variables first and then do `mkdir -p`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create the variables at the beginning of your script and use them later in your mkdir as following:

```
LOGPATH=/path/to/somedir
....
mkdir -p ${LOGPATH} 
....
```